# Getting the caret position of currently opened file in terms of rows and columns in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating an extension in Visual Studio that should give the current row and current column of the caret in the currently opened file.

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text;

namespace TestProject
{
    [Command(PackageIds.MyCommand)]
    internal sealed class MyCommand : BaseCommand<MyCommand>
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(OleMenuCmdEventArgs e)
        {
            var docView = await VS.Documents.GetActiveDocumentViewAsync();
            SnapshotPoint position = docView.TextView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
            var selection = docView?.TextView.Selection.SelectedSpans.FirstOrDefault();
            if (selection.HasValue)
            {
                var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();   
                docView.TextBuffer.Replace(selection.Value, position.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program prints the position in terms of character ( Like the caret is currently at pos 15) but not in terms of row and columns.
Any help?